# Briggs and Stratton yard machine mower

Tags: gasoline, lawnmower, briggs-stratton

My 2yr old mower puts too much gas in the carburetor . It fills up behind the air filter. not safe ...
 DO you have a reason why it might do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If the carb is getting too much fuel, there is one of three reasons, all of them related.

1. The float isn't working. If the float longer *floats*, it will allow fuel to keep allowing fuel into the float bowl, and therefore the carburetor even when it shouldn't.
2. The needle and seat, which are attached to the float, are not sealing correctly. They could be worn out, or deteriorated.
3. The float may be maladjusted. Most B&S carbs I've seen do not have a float adjustment on them, but this would also allow too much fuel to enter the bowls. (Note: This cause is highly unlikely on a B&S engine, unless there was some kind of physical damage to the carb.)

You can attempt to pull the bowl off of the carb to see if there is anything which can be worked. There should only be one bolt at the bottom of the bowl and then a circular gasket (could be an o-ring) where the bowl meets the carb. Just be careful to understand how the parts come apart and go back together.

You can easily get replacement needle/seat/floats in a carb rebuild kit for your engine, but you'd need to look up your specific model to do so. Replacement of these parts are pretty easy as well.